# jQuery Search/Filter not working for list of State/Cities ul li

Tags: jquery, html, search

**BACKGROUND:**

What I'm trying to achieve is to show a list of States in the beginning. Now we've two options, on clicking a state, the list of it's respective cities shall toggle down and the second option is to use the search box which filters cities for all states & on clearing the search hides everything.

**ISSUE:**

The problem I'm facing is over the search end only! The search is working perfectly fine over my test data, but when live data is entered, the search works from second character only e.g. Searching for the city ***Aberdeen***; the search will work if we search for ***berdeen*** rather than ***Aber..***

**Test Data Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/nLjv6u2c/71/

**Live Data Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/nLjv6u2c/72/

**HTML:**

```
<input type='text' id='cityFilter' />
<ul id="stateCityList">
    <li class="state">MARYLAND</li>
    <ul class="cities">
      <li class="city">Aberdeen</li>
      <li class="city">Danville</li>
      <li class="city">Kensington</li>
      <li class="city">Queenstown</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="state">VIRGINIA</li>
    <ul class="cities">
      <li class="city">Abingdon</li>
      <li class="city">Dublin</li>
      <li class="city">Linton Hall</li>
      <li class="city">Marshall</li>    
    </ul>
    <li class="state">WASHINGTON</li>
    <ul class="cities">
      <li class="city">Aberdeen</li>
      <li class="city">Easton</li>
      <li class="city">Lynnwood</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
/* Hide all Cities on page load */
$('.cities').each(function() {$(this).hide();});

$('#cityFilter').on('keyup', function () {
  var value = this.value;
  if (value != "") {
    $('#stateCityList ul li').hide().each(function () {
      if ($(this).not('.state').text().search(value) > -1) {
        $(this).prevAll('.state').first().add(this).show();
        $(this).parent('ul').show();
      }
    });
  } else {
    /* Make sure all hidden Cities are shown on search clear to support toggle functionality*/
    $('#stateCityList ul li').show().each(function () {
        $(this).prevAll('.state').first().add(this).show();
        $(this).parent('ul').show();
    });
    /* Hide all Cities on search clear */
    $('.cities').hide();
  }
});
$('.state').click(function() {
  $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Could be because of the case of the word. Searching for Aber... works on the live fiddle, however searching for aber... doesn't. You will probably need to make the search case insensitive.

Comment: Yes .. you're right! But making the value not case sensitive for jQuery search() function isn't working as well!

Added the code below at Line 7
`value = "/"+value+"/i";`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp

Comment: Chaning this line ```if ($(this).not('.state').text().search(value) > -1)``` to ```if ($(this).not('.state').text().toLowerCase().search(value.toLowerCase()) > -1)``` I was able to search for 'aber..'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making both the value and the search to lower case will make the search work.

Change:

```
if ($(this).not('.state').text().search(value) > -1)
```

To:

```
if ($(this).not('.state').text().toLowerCase().search(value.toLowerCase()) > -1)
```